# Call function from another component not working with EventEmitter()

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I need to call function from component A to vomponent B.
I made service for get users
`service.ts`

```
getUsers(): Observable<UserModel[]> {
return this.httpClient.get<UserModel[]>(environment.BASE_URL + this.apiurlAllUsers + "all").pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

}

And in `component A` I call this service and set data for ng-bootstrap table

```
 getUsersInList() {
this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((data: UserModel[]) => {
  this.collectionSize = data.length;
  this.allUsers = data;
});
}
```

Now when iI submit data in `component B` (my modal box), call function `getUsersInList()` from `component A`

I try use `@Output`

```
component B
@Output trigger: new EventEmitter();

submitForm(){
   this.trigger.emit("hello from B");
}


 component A
 parentFn($event: string) {
console.log($event);
this.getUsersInList();
}
```

And nothing happened...

Also, I try

```
@Input second: componentA
and directly call function

this.second.getUserInList() //but I get errors
```

Thnx

Comment: What's the point of this line: `tap(data => data)`?

Comment: @mbojko only for debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i can't see You htmls but if componentA is a parent of componentB then there should be something like this:

```
 <app-component-b (trigger)=functionThatIsInParent($event)>
```

thats how You pass Output to parent.

EDIT FOR OBSERVABLES: 
in service create a subject:

```
public whatever = new Subject<any>();
```

then You have to create this:

```
getThatObservable(): Observable<any> {
    return.this.whatever.asObservable();
}
```

and also this:

```
updateObservable(data) {
   this.whatever.next(data);
}
```

then on submit:

```
submitForm(){ this.service.updateObservable("hello from B"); }
```

Then in componentA:

```
this.service.getThatObservable().subscribe( data => {
         // do whatever with data
      });
```

Of course that just one of the solutions You can also do not create that updateObservable and just call:

```
this.service.whatever.next("hello from B");
```

Comment: Component A is list with users, and component B is a modal box witch I call on button click. They are different components, not parents and children...

Comment: ok so Output wont work here. You need to create an observable to do so. I will update the answer